# USB Ports are not working in BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, drivers, bios, port

I have a Lenovo H530S desktop with 6 USB Ports. 2 USB 2.0 (Black) Ports at the front, 2 USB 3.0 (Blue) Ports and 2 USB 2.0 (Black) Ports at the rear.
Only 1 USB 2.0 (Black) Port is working in BIOS or at boot time. Rest of the Ports are not working. USB 3.0 (Blue) Ports are working when PC is up & running and detecting the USB 3.0 drive but not detecting the keyboard & mouse (i.e USB 2.0). when I plugin the USB drive in any of the USB port, it starts blinking (i.e Ports are getting power when Windows is running).
Please assist to make the rest of the USB ports working.

**Problem**

- 2 USB 3.0 (Blue) Ports and 1 USB 2.0 (Black) Port are not working in BIOS
- USB 3.0 (Blue) Ports are only detecting the USB 3.0 drive while the Windows is Up and running

**Troubleshooting Done**

- USB Ports are enabled in BIOS
- Tried to update the drivers from Device Manager, already best drivers installed
- Uninstalled USB Root Hub, Standard USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller and USB 3.0 from the Device manager to let windows get the USB drivers
- Installed Chipset drivers from the manufacturer (Lenovo) site
- Installed Lenovo Vantage to get the latest drivers, already up to date
- Tried third party (IOBit Driver Booster) Driver updater tool
- Updated BIOS
- Disable "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power" from USB properties
- Disabled USB Selective suspend setting from Power Options
- Installed Windows Updates

Still, I am facing the same problem. USB 3.0 Ports are only working when Windows in Up and running and only detecting the USB 3.0 devices. Please assist.

Comment: I have similar issue with Thinkpad x220, it has usb 3.0 which works and 2 other usb 2.0 ports that do not work. I think it might be linked with ACPI tables not loaded correctly during linux boot but i do not know how to fix this. Setting grub acpi=off option fails to boot the system entirely.